# Kotlin: groupBy and convert to other object

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects

```
data class OldFormat(ShiftId: Int, NozzleValue: Int, NozzleId: Int , UserId: Int)
```

which I want to group by two of fields "shiftId and userId" and then subtract the maximum value of each group from the minimum value of  the same group and then
sum the result and then convert it to a new object with this class:

```
data class NewFormat(ShiftId: Int, NozzleValue: Int, UserId: Int)
```

The process would be like this:

```
listOfOldFormat -> groupby(shiftId, userId) -> sum(maximumValue-minimumValue) -> listOfNewFormat
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have `groupBy` function, so we have everything we need.

I am not sure what do you mean by

> subtract the maximum value of each group from the minimum value of the same group and then sum the result

What should I sum? So, I did it as `group.value.max - group.value.min` and it's `nozzeValue` for `NewFormat`.

Code snippet:

```
data class OldFormat(val shiftId: Int, val nozzleValue: Int, val nozzleId: Int, val userId: Int)
data class NewFormat(val shiftId: Int, val nozzleValue: Int, val userId: Int)

fun main() {
    
    val old = listOf(
            OldFormat(0, 10, 10, 0),
            OldFormat(0, 120, 10, 1),
            OldFormat(1, 11, 8, 10),
            OldFormat(0, 10, 1, 1),
            OldFormat(1, 50, 10, 10)
    ) // Example data

    old.groupBy {
        it.shiftId to it.userId // After it we have Map<Key, List<OldFormat>>, where key is pair of shiftId and userId
    }.map { entry ->
        val max = entry.value.maxBy { it.nozzleValue }?.nozzleValue ?: 0
        val min = entry.value.minBy { it.nozzleValue }?.nozzleValue ?: 0

        entry.key to (max - min) // Just do whatever you want with that data
    }.map {
        NewFormat(
                shiftId = it.first.first,
                userId = it.first.second,
                nozzleValue = it.second
        ) // And now map it into type you want
    }.let {
        println(it) // Just for seeing result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried your code, it works before mapping to NewFormat but the "it" keyword does not work inside NewFormat object

Comment: I need to put the sum of (max - min) inside nozzleValue of NewFormat object

Comment: But for one grup you can have only one min and only one max. I don't know what should be summed up.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the sum of  (max - min ) of all groups

Comment: Your sample is simplifiable to `old.groupBy({ it.shiftId to it.userId }, OldFormat::nozzleValue).map { (keyPair, values) -> NewFormat(keyPair.first, values.max()!! - values.min()!!, keyPair.second) }`

Comment: Note also, that at each `groupBy`- or `map`-step you basically create and fill a new `Map`.